# Synchronised scrolling of HTML file and eww buffer

Tags: html, scrolling, eww

I am editing a HTML file.

I have done `C-x 3`. Now, in the other split window, I want to open a browser, such as `eww`.

And as I move in the HTML file, I want the browser window to show the corresponding part and vice versa.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I've got already an approximative search to get from a point in the eww buffer to the corresponding place in the html buffer. I think something like that is the starting point to develop a synchronized view. Maybe synchronization with some idle timer.